# Как загружать моментально страницу WebView2 / CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Есть html файл, открыть его не проблема, но загружается он где то секунду, возможно ли при загрузке приложения сохранять страницу в озу или в кэше, что бы при любом открытии страница не светилась белым и не проходило 0.3-1 секунд что бы загрузить страницу

Comment: загружется откуда? По сети? С того же компа? Весит страница сколько? Если она на том же компе, то чтение скорее всего быстро происходит, а вот рендеринг нет.

Comment: загружается Monaco Editor из index.html файла, папка с Монако рядом с приложением

Comment: Код для воспроизведения проблемы вы конечно же не покажете.

Comment: https://ctrlv.link/BsFR